# file_get_contents displaying image incorrectly

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to display generic websites and URLs as part of my own site. Here's part of the relatively simple code I'm using:

**browse.php**

```
<?   
$enteredurl = $_GET["url"];
$page = file_get_contents($enteredurl);
echo $page;
?>
```

Ignoring the fact that some links/images will not work if the URls are relative rather than absolute, this works just fine. Pages are accessed using $_GET, something like

**browse.php?url=http://itracki.com**

The webpage will display as expected. However, when I'm trying to get something else, like an image, I get something like this, which I'm thinking is binary or something?

**browse.php?url=http://images.itracki.com/2011/06/favicon.png**

````
‰PNG  IHDRóÿa%IDAT8Ëc8sæÌJ0M ```ã3`xaÔ€aa]r#f.–ÄíNIEND®B`‚
````

I've been looking online and tried modifying the page headers, something like

```
<? header('Content-type: image/png;'); ?>
```

but I'm still getting the same jumbled up result. Does anyone know how I can actually see the image as it is if I were just accessing it by typing "http://images.itracki.com/2011/06/favicon.png" into the address bar?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope someone malicious doesn't do something like `?url=../../../../../etc/apache2/.htpasswd` or similar.

Comment: use readfile function => readfile($enteredurl) its faster, your header function must be at the top of first script

Comment: Thanks sberry, I'll consider that. @Kirugan, I cannot use readfile because I must be able to modify the code from file_get_contents. What I posted was not my full code, I'm using other functions like str_replace to modify the $page variable.

Comment: @kirugan By the way, changing file_get_contents to readfile still doesn't display the image. Instead I'm getting "‰PNG  IHDRóÿa%IDAT8Ëc8sæÌJ0M ```ã3`xaÔ€aa]r#f.–ÄíNIEND®B`‚94" which is the same as what I posted earlier, only with the extra " ,94"

Comment: The `Content-Type` should just be `image/png`, without the semicolon.  I assume that's just a typo in your question and not your actual code.  Try using `curl` to dump the full headers and body of what your web server is actually sending.

Comment: @tomlogic are you sure it's without the colon? Everywhere else I've seen it the colon is included.

Comment: Moved header to the beginning of the document, now I'm getting an image, but it's that placeholder thing for when there's an error displaying the real image. Kinda like http://i42.tinypic.com/34gr8nm.gif

Comment: Yes, the colon separates the header name from its value -- `Content-Type: image/png`, but your question includes a semicolon at the end (`image/png;`).

Comment: Ah. Yes, that must have been a typo. Didn't see it, my bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $img = 'http://images.itracki.com/2011/06/favicon.png';
  $info = getimagesize($img);
  header('Content-type: ' . $info['mime']);
  readfile($img);
?>
```

You should use `readfile()` instead of `file_get_contents()` in this situation because `readfile()` will send the file contents directly to the browser rather than storing it in memory for a later retrieval, which is what `file_get_contents()` does.

Also note that the `content-type` is retrieved dynamically so that you don't have to worry about specifying it incorrectly in the header.

Some images may have an extension that doesn't match its `content-type` or `mime-type`,  so this corrects for those type of issues.

Comment: Thanks! That got the image displaying properly. As you said, this works great because even if the file is named with the incorrect extension, it will still display the correct mime-type.

Comment: This works.  One gotcha is that this code snippet must stand-alone in its own dedicated php file.   I had some authentication code in the lines above, and somehow the browser was looking that and deciding the page is unknown raw data even though I asserted its type using the `header(...)` method.

Answer (score 5):

try this one

```
$image = 'http://images.itracki.com/2011/06/favicon.png';
// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo '<img src="',$src,'">';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo 'data:;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://images.itracki.com/2011/06/favicon.png'));
```

Comment: You'll have to elaborate. Also this is not applicable to the situation as described by the asker.