# integrate an image with link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Well, I think it might be easier to explain my question by the image below:

[image]

As can be seen in the picture, if user select "By title", a textbox will be appeared where user can write a movie title (I also used jQuery auto-completion for this textbox). Then, if user click on the button "Movies by this title", a new window will be shown where there is a list of movies containing the term in the textbox.

My question:

I would like to integrate a small image of each of these movies beside them (and maybe some other information like movie year, genre..) like what amazon does ([Please see here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_5?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=wolf%20of%20wall%20street&sprefix=wolf%20%2Caps%2C204&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Awolf%20of%20wall%20street)). I used renderitem for the auto-complete part and it works fine, but actually I have no idea how to do the same in the new window.. I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

This is my code:

```
<div id="m_scents" class="field">
   <label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts"></label>
   <input class="autofill4" type="textbox" name= "q27[]" id="q" placeholder="Enter movie titles here" />
   <input type="button" value="Movies by this title" id="btnMove" style="display:none;"/> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selected;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id='selectType']").change(function(){
         if ($(this).val() == "byTitle") {
              $("#m_scents2").hide();
              $("#btnMove").show();
              $("#m_scents").show();
              $("#q").focus();
              $("#q").autocomplete({
                   minLength: 0,
                   delay:5,
                   source: "query.php",
                   focus: function( event, ui ){
                             event.preventDefault();
                             return false;
                        },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                             window.selected = ui.item.movieName;
                             return false;
                        }
              }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + (item.posterLink?"<img class='imdbImage' src='imdbImage.php?url=" + item.posterLink + "' />":"") + "<span class='imdbTitle'>" + item.movieName + "</span>" + "<div class='clear'></div></a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
                };
        }
  });

$('#btnMove').on('click', function (e) {
      popupCenter("movieBytitle.php","_blank","400","400");
});
</script>
```

This is movieBytitle.php:

```
<body>
<div id= "field"
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var selected = parent.window.opener.selected; 
 $.ajax({
   url: 'childfilm.php',
   datatype: "json",
   data:{p:selected},
   success: function(response) {     
         $("#field").html(response);
     }
  });
</script>
</body>
```

and this is childfilm.php:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])){
  try{ 
    include('imdbConnection.php');
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM films WHERE movieName LIKE :p");
    $sql->execute(array(':p' => '%'.$_GET['p'].'%'));

    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $option = '<a href=movie.php?title="' . $row['movieName'] . '">' . $row['movieName'] . '</a><br />';
       $html .= $option;

       }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
           echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
       }
   echo $html; 
   exit;
 }
?>
```

UPDATE:

This is the new childfilm.php (Thanks to @ghost help):

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])){
    include('imdbConnection.php');
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM films WHERE movieName LIKE :p");
    $sql->execute(array(':p' => '%'.$_GET['p'].'%'));
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img class='imdbImage' src='imdbImage.php?url="<?php echo $row['posterLink'];?>'</td>
        <td><a href="movie.php?title=<?php echo urlencode($row['movieName']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

and this is imdbImage.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$url = rawurldecode($_REQUEST['url']);
echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

New problem:

This is the result (Still, the image is not shown properly):
[image]

Comment: are the image path, and other info like movie year, genre saved also in table? just include it in the fetching

Comment: you just need to edit the html you build in `childfilm.php`. Also, the use of ajax in the popup window is redundant. You could instead send the selected parameter via get parameter, and run the php code directly in `movieBytitle.php`. Lastly, popup windows are frequently blocked by anti advert software, so are best avoided

Comment: here the implementation as same http://jsfiddle.net/9GbkL/5/

Comment: @Ghost: yes, I have image links of movies + their year and genre

Comment: i would love to visit this site once it finishes. looks so cool!

Comment: @ShailendraSharma: tnx , but my question was NOT integrate image in autocompletion list (which I already did and works fine), but in a new window page..

Comment: @itachi: really? :) happy to hear that :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already got those information in the table, then just include it in the fetching and present it in tabular form:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])){

    include('imdbConnection.php');

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT movieName FROM films WHERE movieName LIKE :p");
    $sql->execute(array(':p' => '%'.$_GET['p'].'%'));

}

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="path/to/images/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" alt="" /></td>
        <td><a href="movie.php?title=<?php echo urlencode($row['movieName']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['genre']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for help, I will try it now and inform you of the result.

Comment: @mOna sure no prob hope it turns out well.

Comment: sorry if this is something basic, but I don't know how can I pass the table data (movie link + images) to movieBytitle page.. (for example, before, I put all rows in $option ..) how does it work now?

Comment: @mOna wait, can you walk me thru this one, i can't understand whats going on. what are you trying to do now? you're trying to pass the url inside `<img src="<here>"`?

Comment: actually what I want is: when click the button "movieas by this title", it will shows movies (movie links) + small image beside each movie (like http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_6?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=top+gun&sprefix=top+gu%2Caps%2C205&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Atop+gun )... but what I see now, is only links of movies... (there should be some problem with images that I don't know that)

Comment: @mOna of course, those `$row['year'], $row['genre'], $row['filename']` are just hypothetical values. you need to change that to fit into yours since i don't know what your column names are (table structure and values inside it) as it isn't posted/included in your question. those are just examples. try to change it and match it into yours

Comment: I changed `$row['filename']` to `$row['posterLink']`, where `posterLink` is the name of the column in my table "films". I also changed `path/to/images/` to `imdbImage.php` where decode the url of images. `imdbImage.php` cotain these 2 line of codes: `$url = rawurldecode($_REQUEST['url']);`, `echo file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to define url ,

Comment: @mOna try to use this answer instead and kindly check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14251604/3859027

Comment: thanks for your support, actually this worked for me: `<td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>`